# Webapplication: icons take long to load

Tags: load

I'm using a few icons in a webpage. But they take a long to load from disk, around .8 seconds for around 300 kB. See image.
How come, or is that normal? And more important, how can I improve load speed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can compress them http://www.punypng.com/

And/or you can combine them into one image: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp that would help with the amount of requests.